# gaps between square roots of primes

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

It is well known that the difference $p_{n+1}-p_n$ can be arbitrarily large.

What about $\sqrt{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt{p_n}$, or in general, $p_{n+1}^t-p_n^t$ for $t<1$?
Has this problem been investigated? I found no answer, but maybe I just don't know what it is called.

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture

Comment: thanks for this, but my question is much weaker: I asked if $p_{p+1}^x-p_n^x$ is bounded from above, while the conjecture is about this being bounded by 1.

Comment: You are asking if there is always a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+d)^2$, that is conjectured to be true but not known... also look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture